# Redirect loop when setting port via environment variable in forcedomain (node.js, express)

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, redirect-loop

I use [forcedomain](https://github.com/thenativeweb/forcedomain) middleware in my  [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) application with [express](http://expressjs.com/) framework to get redirects to default domain.

When I specify port in forcedomain settings explicitly, it works well, for example in a trivial 'hello world' application:

```
var express = require('express') 
var app = express() 
var forceDomain = require('forcedomain') 

app.use(forceDomain({ 
    hostname:'example.com', 
    port:3000 
})) 


app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
      res.send('Hello World') 
}) 

app.listen(3000)
```

But then I decided to set all configurable variables via environment (i.e., to have different ports in development or production mode).
So I changed the cited above code - replaced 3000 with `process.env.PORT`:

```
...
app.use(forceDomain({ 
    hostname:'example.com', 
    port:process.env.PORT 
}))     
...
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

and run the application as following

```
$ PORT=3000 node app.js
```

But this time, if I enter `http://example.com:3000` in browser, I get an redirect-loop error: "This webpage has a redirect loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)"

I tried to use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) package to load environment variables from .env file, and added the following at the beginning of my application:

```
require('dotenv').load()
```

but result was the same - redirect loop.

It looks like `app.listen` gets the proper value from `process.env.PORT`, while forcedomain doesn't and starts with default port setting (80).

So this question is still open to me: how to pass the env. variable to forcedomain settings?

**update1**

Versions are fresh:

```
$ node -v
v0.12.2
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "forcedomain-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^1.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.0",
    "forcedomain": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.use(forceDomain({ 
  hostname : 'example.com', 
  port     : Number(process.env.PORT)
}))
```

`forceDomain` does a strict match against the port number in use (which it turns into a number first) and the port set in the options (which, because it's coming from an environment variable, is a string).

Since strings and numbers don't match when performing strict equality checking, `forceDomain` thinks it has to issue a redirect.

Comment: thank you, @robertklep, it does work! 
Maybe, the package should handle such situation by itself?

Comment: @hooke I guess there's something to be said that the package would convert to a number, although it could also state that `port` should be a number (and it won't work properly if it isn't)

Comment: the redirect loop trouble repeated when I set PORT to 80. 
The only workaround I've found is not to set port in forcedomain settings, i.e. `app.use(forceDomain({ hostname : 'example.com' }))`
Am I wrong when explicitly set port of forceDomain to default value (80)?

Comment: @hooke if the port isn't present in the `Host` header, `forcedomain` uses a value of `undefined` to compare against. So in your case, by not setting the `port` option, the match works (`undefined === undefined`), but IMO this is a bug in `forcedomain` (it should default to port 80).

Comment: so, since `forcedomain` now uses `undefined` for missed port in the `Host` header, universal workaround (for any port) could be like this: `var webport = Number(process.env.PORT); app.use(forceDomain({ hostname : 'example.com', port: (webport == 80) ? undefined : webport }))`

Comment: @hooke that's correct. I created [an issue](https://github.com/thenativeweb/forcedomain/issues/8) regarding the port 80 thing.